# Entering data directly via table view swift 4

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I’m having a play about with table views and saving data. I’ve managed to created an add button where you can add some data to a table view (like a to do list app) and it saves in user defaults. However, I can’t seem to figure out how to add and save data directly just by pressing an empty row in the table view. Basically, I would like to know how to add data and display data on a table view just like the stock To Do and Reminders app from Apple.

I’m working with Swift 4.

Any help or code examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not an empty row. It's a row with a text field or text view.

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/2153-how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1-2

Comment: send your code please